# Voxelgrid where the true position of each voxel is returned

Tags: ros, pcl, voxel-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the [voxelgrid tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/voxel_grid.php#voxelgrid), it is stated that:

> ...in each voxel (i.e., 3D box), all the points present will be approximated (i.e., downsampled) with their centroid. This approach is a bit slower than approximating them with the center of the voxel, but it represents the underlying surface more accurately.

I would like to instead downsample a point cloud and get the true centroid of each *voxel*, thus maintaining a regular grid. However, I couldn't find an option for this in [the documentation](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_voxel_grid.html). Is this possible in the current PCL version?

In addition, is it possible to get, for each resulting voxel, the number of points that fell into it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11870/voxelgrid-where-the-true-position-of-each-voxel-is-returned/) by [BillCheetham](https://answers.ros.org/users/1345/billcheetham/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-11-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This should probably be taken to the pcl-users mailing list.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0